# How to change delay of animation with Sal.js

Tags: javascript, function

I have a project, in this project I use the animation js library Sal.js, you can have a delay of the animation and that's all great if you have a header for example, but I want to delay to go once the animation has already played and every time the user replays it there is no delay, I don't know if this is possible with sal its self.

I tried changing the delay with javascript but failed but I'm sure I can do it manually

here is the header

```html
   <header class="masthead">
     <div class="overlay h-100">
       <div class="container h-100">
         <div class="row h-100 align-items-center font-weight-bold">
           <div data-sal-duration="1200" data-sal="slide-up" data-sal-delay="700" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bounce" id="masthead-text" class="col-12 text-center text-light">
             <h1 class="display-3">title here</h1>
             <p class="lead">here is a sub title</p>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </header>
```

```
    <script>
      sal();
    </script>`enter code here`
```

and I have already done the sal in the javascript

i think it would be possible doing a condition that if the animation is played once then the delay goes, thanks in advance

Comment: How is the user replaying it? I see it occur once in your example and then stop.

Comment: @Bryan what do you mean? its onscroll and that means once its in view the the animation plays, and if you set the animation to replay if the user scroll out of view and back again it will play again however with the same delay